# Bash glob expansion like echo $pathInVar*

Tags: bash, glob, expansion

I have a variable containing a path and want to expand a glob pattern based on that path. I want to understand why my attempts don't work and what is the preferred way of doing this in bash.

**EX**: I want to list all text files in my home directory or only those that starts with "test". My *failing* attempts:

```
foo="~/"
echo $foo*.txt
echo ${foo}test*.txt
```

These results in the string outputs `~/*` and `~/test*txt` respectively. I have tried different versions with quotes etc. but I guess this enough to show my issue and level of understanding — I am a bash beginner. Is the issue related to tilde expansion vs. using $HOME?

Ultimately, I want to loop over these files but I ask this question to understand bash, not just get the result.

P.S. I am certain there are answers to this already out there but I've not managed to find any that have helped me understand this case. I tried to understand the general expansion order in bash but still don't understand how to apply it here.

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect you see. For me, a `foo="~/"; echo $foo*.txt` simply outputs _~/*.txt_, and if I turn on _failglob_, I get of course _bash: no match: ~/*.txt_.

Comment: My bad. I had two versions of the question and mixed up the output. I have adjusted it accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a glob, `*` matches any character in a file name but it does **not** match `/`.  Thus, to get files in your home directory, try:

```
foo=$HOME
echo $foo/*.txt
echo ${foo}/test*.txt
```

In the odd case that `foo` (`$HOME`) includes shell-active characters, it is better practice to use:

```
echo "$foo"/*.txt
echo "${foo}"/test*.txt
```

To loop over such files, use:

```
for fname in "$foo"/*.txt
do
    # do something
done
```

This loop structure is safe for all filenames, even ones with spaces or other shell-active characters.  This, of course, assumes that the code in your loop has `$fname` inside double-quotes as appropriate.

#### Update for revised question

```
foo="~/"
```

`~/` never expands when inside quotes:

```
$ foo="~/"
$ echo $foo
~/
```

If you really want to use `~/`, don't use quotes.  Unless you want to use one of the fancy features of `~`, it is usually simpler and more reliable to use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to list them, you can simply go with

```sh
ls "${HOME}"/*.txt # or echo "$HOME"/*.txt

# Output
# /Users/meirgabay/file1.txt      /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt      /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt
```

If you want to iterate over files paths, here's how

```sh
declare -a _TXT_FILES=()
for file_path in "$HOME"/*.txt; do
    echo "$file_path"
    _TXT_FILES+=("$file_path")
done

echo "${_TXT_FILES[@]}"

# Output
# /Users/meirgabay/file1.txt
# /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt
# /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt
# /Users/meirgabay/file1.txt /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt
```

I used an array, `declare -a _TXT_FILES=()`, to store the results in a variable.

If you want to use `~/` instead of `$HOME`, that's also possible, just make sure you don't surround it with quotes.
The `~` character is expanded by bash, and if you put it between quotes, it is evaluated as a string, instead of getting expanded.

```
ls ~/*.txt
/Users/meirgabay/file1.txt      /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt      /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt

# Output
# /Users/meirgabay/file1.txt      /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt      /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt

echo ~/*.txt
/Users/meirgabay/file1.txt /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt

# Output
# /Users/meirgabay/file1.txt /Users/meirgabay/file2.txt /Users/meirgabay/some_file.txt
```

Comment: So it is the tilde expansion inside foo that is the culprit?

Comment: @Stalpotaten , updated my answer, let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Hah, no worries, you found your answer, and that's the important part